# How to track Linq2Db add,update,delete events?

Tags: .net-core, linq2db, asp.net-core-2.2

How can I track events on adding, updating or deleting entity rows with Linq2Db?

I need to recalculate some data in db on this operations, what is the best way?

On Entity Framework I use my custom Repository class with custom Add operations. Mabe this is only way in Linq2Db, but I am interesing, mabe there is some catcher to notify this events?

Comment: sorry I misread your question and deleted my answer :) I took a look at the docs of Linq2Db and couldn't find a recommended way of doing this. Maybe have a look at [this](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/issues/331) or [this](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/issues/553) github issue.

Answer (score 6):

It is not so easy as in EF, because linq2db manipulates with SQL and you can easily update thousands records by single update statement.
For example

```
db.SomeEntities.Where(e => e.IsExpired)
  .Set(e => e.ExpirationDate, e => Sql.CurrentTimestamp)
  .Update();
```

The same technique can be used with `insert from`, `update from`, `delete`.

But there is possibility to catch SQL AST before executing. You have to override `ProcessQuery` method in your `DataConnection` class.
Sample is here: [ConcurrencyCheckTests.cs](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/blob/master/Tests/Linq/Samples/ConcurrencyCheckTests.cs#L47)

You should return the same statement that is passed to method but with changed property `statement.IsParameterDependent = true` to prevent query caching.

`SqlStatement` analysis is not trivial task but possible. You have to handle `SqlUpdateStatement`, `SqlInsertStatement`, `SqlDeleteStatement`, `SqlInsertOrUpdateStatement`.

Second option is to write your own extensions which manipulates with single objects, for example, `UpdateTracked()`, `DeleteTracked()`, etc. But as you can see from first example it will not help in complex queries.

Comment: Thanks  for your answer. I desided to do the simplest way, do it in buisness logic layer on Update, Insert, Delete operations.